# losing internet connection via router

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection

I have been experiencing a weird behavior regarding my home network setup that started about 3 days ago. I have a this particular setup for over a year now and never had any problems.

My main router is a SMC7004VBR Barricade that is connected with my PC with Vista Home Premium and a D-Link DIR-628 Wireless router.

Whenever I unplug the WAN connection in my SMC router, I am able to log into both routers. But as soon as I connect the cable from my DSL-modem to the SMC WAN port, not only do I not get any access to the internet but I can't even login to my routers anymore.

I have tried changing the cable between the modem and the SMC router to no avail. I tried doing a reset on the SMC router but no luck there either. The only way I can get internet access is if I directly plug my PC into the modem.

I also tried to do a system restore to about a week ago thinking that a Windows update might be the culprit. But I still get no access to the internet via my home network.

Now I do not have a wireless connection available plus I have no barrier between the internet and my PC.

Can somebody point me in the right direction on where to look or what might be the cause of this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like your internal and external networks might be conflicting.  What address do you use to log in to the router, and what address gets assigned to the PC when connected directly to the modem?

Comment: hi karl,

I use 192.168.2.x to login into both routers and the ip i get when connected directly to the modem is 24.80.100.x. I initially thought that it might be the case and that there is a conflict with regards to the ip. i did a relase and renew of my ip a couple of times but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
Seems to me you need to setup your wireless router AS Access point, not AS router.
At this point your wireless router get IP address from main router.

Try to reset both of your router to factory default setting and start from scratches:)

If you plug the the cable from the primary router to the LAN port (and not internet port) of the secondary 625 and disable the DHCP server (and firewall) on the same secondary router, clients connected through the secondary router (wired or wireless) will receive IP addresses from the DHCP pool of the primary router.  When setup the way just described, the second 625 will effectively bridge clients to the primary router without any NAT on the second router.  Its LAN ports will act like a switch and its wirelss will act like a WAP, but only if cable runs LAN to LAN port (and DHCP is disabled).  This is true for any router because there is not NAT only bridging and switching.
Also to make your life easier, change the LAN IP addresses of all gateways, routers and switches so that they are all on the same subnet - this will make switch/router management much easier.  At least the twp 625's should be on the same subnet (the DSL modem does not really matter because you really never touch).

Comment: Hi Stalker,

Thanks for your answer and advise. I did setup the network just as you described. I've disabled the DHCP server for the wireless router and is connected to the primary via LAN to LAN port. I also forgot to mention that during my troubleshooting/test, I disconnected the wireless and I still cannot connect to the internet. That is why I sort of think that it was the primary router that's the problem.

What is baffling is that my particular setup has been running perfectly for about a year now and all of a sudden this happens. If you have any more suggestion please let me know. TNX!

Comment: ok, did you try to connect modem directly to computer? do you have internet connection this way?
How your primary router setup?
DHCP? static IP? PPPoE?
When you connect your PC to the router: start>run>cmd>ipconfig /all
what is IP address, subnet, Default gateway and DNS?
When you connect your PC directly to the modem:start>run>cmd>ipconfig /all
what is IP address, subnet, Default gateway and DNS?
Please post it here

Comment: Hello Stalker,

It seems that my primary router is about to go kaput! I retired the SMC router and reconfigured the D-Link. I now am back online with a router.

Thanks for the input and advise.